# Which Rust 1.2 containers support trait objects?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

In the Rust Edition Guide it says that in Rust 1.2, [more container types support trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/more-container-types-support-trait-objects.html). It gave the example of `Rc<T>`, but it didn't give a complete list. What other containers support trait objects in Rust 1.2+?

Answer (score 3):

Containers that support trait objects are containers that have a [`?Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) bound on their containee type.

By default with generics, all types are `Sized` implicitly as this is what you want most of the time, and adding a `Sized` on almost every generic would be annoying. This behaviour is different from other traits and can be avoided by adding a `?Sized` bound.

```rust
struct Foo<T>; // implicit `T: Sized` bound. T cannot be a trait object.

struct Bat<T: ?Sized>; // T can be a trait object.
```

You can [see on the repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/7d953538d10c4a31300afd27f73563adb056beab#diff-da456bd3af6d94a9693e625ff7303113R213) that `Rc` indeed used to be declared `pub struct Rc<T>` and was later changed to `pub struct Rc<T: ?Sized>`. GitHub lists this change as being part of Rust 1.1, but I guess we had to wait 1.2 to get it in stable.

Other containers that work on trait objects are `Box`, `Arc`, `Cell` and all the like of those smart pointers.

Containers that do not work on trait objects are `Vec`, `HashMap` and generally containers that might store more that one instance (collections). This is because 2 instances of the same trait objects might have different sizes (if they have different concrete type), and collections usually store elements continuously, requiring a constant size.

Comment: Probably worth being specific about the usage of "trait object" here. I think most people would lazily call `Box<dyn Trait>` a "trait object" and that can be put in a `Vec`.